# How to create object from another object JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to convert first variable `entries` into `newEntries` variable?

```js
let entries = {
  "app": "/main/application/src/app/src/pages/app/src/index.js",
  "app1": "/main/application/src/app/src/pages/app/src/app1.js",
  "app2": "/main/application/src/app/src/pages/app/src/app2.js"
}

let newEntries = {
  //from entries should be that:
  app: ["@babel/polyfill", "/main/application/src/app/src/pages/app/src/index.js"],
  app1: ["@babel/polyfill", "/main/application/src/app/src/pages/app/src/app1.js"],
  app2: ["@babel/polyfill", "/main/application/src/app/src/pages/app/src/app2.js"],
}
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.reduce` with `Object.entries` to achieve this. Firstly, `Object.entries` will give you an array of key-value pairs within your `entries` object:

```
[["app", "/main/application/src/app/src/pages/app/src/index.js"], ...]
```

You can then use `.reduce` to build up a new object, which gets every inner array of the above array (ie: gets every key-value) and adds that to the new object. However, the value of the new object is instead an array with the current value with the string `"@babel/polyfill"`.

See implemenation below:

```js
let entries = {
  "app": "/main/application/src/app/src/pages/app/src/index.js",
  "app1": "/main/application/src/app/src/pages/app/src/app1.js",
  "app2": "/main/application/src/app/src/pages/app/src/app2.js"
}

const arr_res = Object.entries(entries).reduce(
                  (acc, [k, v]) => ({...acc, [k]: ["@babel/polyfill", v]}),
                {});
console.log(arr_res);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a shortcut assuming `"@babel/polyfill"` is constant but that is easily changeable.

```js
let entries = {
  "app": "/main/application/src/app/src/pages/app/src/index.js",
  "app1": "/main/application/src/app/src/pages/app/src/app1.js",
  "app2": "/main/application/src/app/src/pages/app/src/app2.js"
};

let newEntries = Object.keys(entries).map(key => [key,["@babel/polyfill", entries[key]]])
                                     .reduce((a,c) => {a[c[0]] = c[1]; return a},{});

console.log(newEntries);
```

If I remember correctly `Object.entries()` is more recent than `Object.keys()` so I will leave this here in case browser support matters.

Answer (score 0):

I see you got a couple of poor answers *(edit: later ones aren't poor)* to this question. To prevent your being sent off in a random direction, you just loop through the properties creating an array with your hardcoded first entry and the property value as the second property. Here's an example using [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) (quite new, but easily polyfilled) and [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) (somewhat new, but easily polyfilled):

```
let newEntries = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(entries).map(([key, value]) => [key, ["@babel/polyfill", value]])
);
```

Live Example:

```js
let entries = {
  "app": "/main/application/src/app/src/pages/app/src/index.js",
  "app1": "/main/application/src/app/src/pages/app/src/app1.js",
  "app2": "/main/application/src/app/src/pages/app/src/app2.js"
};

let newEntries = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(entries).map(([key, value]) => [key, ["@babel/polyfill", value]])
);

console.log(newEntries);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
 }
```

Or doing it manually rather than using those new-ish helpers:

```
let newEntries = {};
for (const key in entries) {
  if (entries.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    newEntries[key] = ["@babel/polyfill", entries[key]];
  }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
let entries = {
  "app": "/main/application/src/app/src/pages/app/src/index.js",
  "app1": "/main/application/src/app/src/pages/app/src/app1.js",
  "app2": "/main/application/src/app/src/pages/app/src/app2.js"
};

let newEntries = {};
for (const key in entries) {
  if (entries.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    newEntries[key] = ["@babel/polyfill", entries[key]];
  }
}

console.log(newEntries);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
 }
```